# Is there any difference in using up/down vs change/reversible methods in Rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

In a Rails migration, does it make any difference, if I do this:

```
def up
  foo
end

def down
  bar
end
```

or this:

```
def change
  reversible do |direction|
    direction.up { foo }
    direction.down { bar }
  end
end
```

?

I think that it's better to use the change method if part of the migration includes reversible methods, such as `create_table`, `add_column` etc.. Other than that, is there any difference?

Comment: @Deep the questions you mention explain what the general difference between `up`/`down` vs `change` is. I do understand that, but my question is related to any differences between `up`/`down` and `reversible` within `change`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you show it, there is no advantage. The main advantage is that a lot of the time you don't need to write the `down` method / block at all, eg

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The `reversible` method is mostly used when there is a small part of a migration that activerecord doesn't know how to reverse (eg a raw SQL statement)

Answer (score 1):

The change method works for many cases where the reversible logic can be derived easily and ActiveRecord migrations can easily handle it.  However, in some cases you may need to do something specific inside of a migration to insure it will run without errors.  There may also be something complex would be an irreversible migration. 
See [Rails: Is it bad to have an irreversible migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621257/rails-is-it-bad-to-have-an-irreversible-migration#621363)

In such cases it is best to use the up down method but there is also away of checking if the current direction of the migration which is simply `reverting?`

Here's an example where you might use this in place of the 2 up/down methods. In this example, there is also a complex data method not show which caused a migration error without the conditional logic.  I've ommited as it is not relevant to your question:

```
def change
  add_column :languages, :iso_639_2t, :string
  add_column :languages, :iso_639_2b, :string
  add_column :languages, :iso_639_3, :string
  add_index :languages, :iso_639_2t
  unless reverting?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    .execute("ALTER SEQUENCE languages_id_seq RESTART WITH #{Language.count+1}")
  end
end
```

If complex data manipulation is used inside of a migration via [migration_data gem](https://github.com/ka8725/migration_data) for example, you might want to add a `def check_data` method and raise an exception if the data_check fails.

If the migration is really irreversible (destroys data), you may want to also use up/down for example:

```
def up
  remove_column :signup, :date
end

def down
  raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Date field dropped in previous migration. Data unrecoverable"
end
```